# Any 'Excel-like' visualization or GUI tools for MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

GUI tools such as MongoDB compass or Studio 3T does not meet below requirements.
I am wondering if any GUI tool for **`MongoDB Aggregation`** which allows me to build **`Aggregation`** via **`Excel-Way (click and select with minor manual commands)`** to get rid of drafting raw MongoDB Aggregation commands, which is quite complicated and **`expensive (too much time and efforts for a simple query)`** to use.

Yes, all those examples for MongoDB Aggregation on official docs are relatively simple, however, when it comes to real world query, even a simple query requires complicated Aggregation command. [check this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360062/how-to-match-string-within-embedded-array-or-doc-in-mongodb/70363057#70363057).

Another example, mongodb does not provide tools for me to check the output of each aggregation command (not stage) one-by-one.

```
db.collection.aggregte([
    {$map:
                 {
                   input: "$quizzes",
                   as: "grade",
                   in: { $add: [ "$$grade", 2 ] }
                 }
    }
])
```

it throws me an error "unknown top level operator: $map"

Comment: `$map` is an _operator_; the error is because you are using it incorrectly.  Aggregation query is made of _Stages_ and _Operators_. And, each stage does some data transformation and passes the data as input to the next stage. Please follow the _syntax_ and _examples_ for each stage and operator form the MongoDB Manual. See: [Aggregation Pipeline Quick Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/).

Comment: I created a tool ([humongous.io](https://www.humongous.io)) that has a fairly decent visual aggregator for basic metrics calculations.